# how dropdown selection can change data

Tags: javascript, math

// i am wondering how to change the code so if "Level2" is selected in the dropdown menu, the numbers in the equations get larger.

```js
var num1 = [];
var num2 = [];
var ans = [];
var msum = [];
function INlist(count)
{
   document.getElementById("demo6").innerHTML = ""
   for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
      num1[i] = 0;
      num2[i] = 0;
      ans[i] = 0;
      msum[i] = 0;
   }

   for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
      num1[i] = Math.ceil(Math.random()*9); // these two lines decide how large the numbers are
      num2[i] = Math.ceil(Math.random()*9); 
      ans[i] = num1[i] + num2[i];

      msum[i] = num1[i] + " + " + num2[i] + " = "
      + "<input id=\"resp" + i + "\" onchange=\"check(this.value)\"    type=\"text\" name=\"fname\"><br>";

      document.getElementById("demo6").innerHTML = document.getElementById  ("demo6").innerHTML + msum[i];
   }
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
<option id="Level1">Level 1</option> // selecting level 2 should make the equations harder 
<option id="Level2">Level 2</option>

</select>

<p id="demo"></p>

<button onclick="INlist(10)">Start!</button>
<p id="demo6"></p>
```

// writing this so my post is eligible to post

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
```

**The line above will generate a random number between 1 and 20.**

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 20 + 1)) + 20;
```

**The line above will generate a random number between 20 and 50.**

Also I wonder why you're using two `for` loops here. When in the first one you're setting every index to zero, while their values are going to be modified right after the first loop is finished.
If you're doing this to reset the values from previous execution of the loop, then you can simply re-initialize the variables like

```
num1 = [];
num2 = [];
```